# add NSTimer to NSArray with UIImages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, nstimer

I am trying to add animation for UIImages which are added in an array. I would like to add animation to array index 0 and make it animated.I want to change the imageCount and animate it every 3 secs. I have also added NSTimer which will help me to change the image but it is not changing the image correctly. I have like a menu list in which the first link should be animated. Has anyone come across such an issue before and can help me out.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(animateFunction) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
[self setListArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"List",@"To-Do",nil]];

}

 -(void)animateFunction
   {
NSLog(@"Timer heartbeat %i",imageCount);
if (imageCount == 2) {
    // set the image count back to initial value;
    imageCount = 1;
} else {
    imageCount++;
}

[self setCellIconNames:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png", imageCount],@"final.png",@"blue.png",nil]];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];


NSString *cellIconName = [[self cellIconNames] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];
[[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];

cell.textLabel.text = [listArray objectAtIndex:row];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `imageCount` is being set to 1 each time you call the method associated with the timer.  Try declaring `imageCount` in the header file as something like `int imageCount;`, remove `imageCount = 1;` from the `animateFunction` method and place it in the `viewDidLoad` or some similar method to initialize it.  Then when you iterate `imageCount` (which you can substitute `imageCount = imageCount + 1` with just `imageCount++` if you like), it will add 1 to the variable properly instead of returning 2 each time (which is what the current method does).  If you need the images to loop, you will need to set up a check that resets the `imageCount` like the following:

```
if (imageCount == yourMaxNumber) {
    // set the image count back to initial value;
    imageCount = 1;
} else {
    imageCount++;
}
```

Hopefully that does the trick for you

Comment: I have a quick question : I cannot set the image at every regular interval of 3 secs from NSTimer. I changed my logic as per your request and have edited my question as above but whenever NSTimer calls the function it does not set the image correctly.

Comment: What exactly is happening? In other words, what exactly do you see going on and what do you want to see? The more detail, the better.  Then we can get everything giong just how you want

Comment: actually currently I am trying to change the image after every interval of 3 secs using NSTimer for [self setCellIconNames:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.png", imageCount]. The image name changes after each 3 secs. I am trying to add the changing images in cellForRowAtIndexPath but it never gets set after 3 secs. I have edited my question more by keeping cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you have a 3 second timer that switches images.  When the image changes, you want it to set the images of the imageView in a tableViewCell.  If so, just add `[self.yourTableView reloadData]`. You can call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` if you only have a select few rows to update, but if there aren't many rows in the first place, it won't make any significant difference and `reloadData` will be fine.  It just sounds to me like you are updating the image, but not updating the cells